# onClickListener of an inflated view is not getting fired

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I  have a child view and a root view. Im trying to add **onClick** listener to child view but the **onClickListener is never getting fired**.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification, container, false);

    linear = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

        childView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.notification_fragment, linear);

        TextView txt = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt.setText("welcome");
        txt.setId(i);
    }

childView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),""+mChildView.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     });
   return rootView;
}
```

notification_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="PI 12343"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

notification.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.stack.widgets.SegmentedButton
        android:id="@+id/segment_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/button_one"
        android:background="#3dd2c6"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@id/button_one"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="33dip"
            android:minWidth="40dip"
            android:text="Pending"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#01A9DB" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button_two"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="33dip"
            android:minWidth="40dip"
            android:text="Completed"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#01A9DB" />
    </com.stack.widgets.SegmentedButton>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/linear"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When the pending radio button is pressed, the childviews will be inflated upon rootview. Childviews should be clickable.

Comment: it was a typo error. I changed it to childView but still it doesn't work

Comment: add a linear/rel layout around textview (if it doesnt exist) in notification_fragment.xml and set onClickListener for that layout id

Comment: still it doesn't work

Comment: can you update the code and xml

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104933/discussion-between-dhina-and-stanly).

Answer (score 0):

set your listener inside for loop, currently it is setting listener for your last view only.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

    childView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.notification_fragment, linear);

    TextView txt = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt.setText("welcome");
    txt.setId(i);

    childView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),""+mChildView.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: still the same problem persists